# Get geolocation of position on SAPUI5 Googlemap?

Tags: google-maps, sapui5

i'm using the SAPUI5 Google Maps library of John Patterson :
https://github.com/jasper07/openui5-googlemaps

Is it possible to handle a click on the map (not on a marker!) and get the geolocation of it ?

gr
Hans

Answer (score 0):

click event was recently added [see search2 demo](http://jasper07.secondphase.com.au/openui5-googlemaps/samples/search2.html)